# facet_wrap Title wrapping & Decimal places on free_y axis (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a set of code that produces multiple plots using `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(summ,aes(x=depth,y=expr,colour=bank,group=bank)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=expr-se,ymax=expr+se),lwd=0.4,width=0.3,position=pd) +
geom_line(aes(group=bank,linetype=bank),position=pd) +
geom_point(aes(group=bank,pch=bank),position=pd,size=2.5) +
scale_colour_manual(values=c("coral","cyan3", "blue")) +
facet_wrap(~gene,scales="free_y") +  
theme_bw()
```

With the reference datasets, this code produces figures like this:

[image: multiplot example]

I am trying to accomplish two goals here:

1. Keep the auto scaling of the y axis, but make sure only 1 decimal place is displayed across all the plots. I have tried creating a new column of the rounded `expr` values, but it causes the error bars to not line up properly.
2. I would like to wrap the titles. I have tried changing the font size as in [Change plot title sizes in a facet_wrap multiplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409981/change-plot-title-sizes-in-a-facet-wrap-multiplot), but some of the gene names are too long and will end up being too small to read if I cram them on a single line. Is there a way to wrap the text, using code within the `facet_wrap` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably cannot serve as definite answer, but here are some pointers regarding your questions:

1. Formatting the y-axis scale labels.

First, let's try the direct solution using `format` function. Here we format all y-axis scale labels to have 1 decimal value, after rounding it with `round`.

```
formatter <- function(...){
  function(x) format(round(x, 1), ...)
}

mtcars2 <- mtcars
sp <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl, scales = "free_y")
sp <- sp + scale_y_continuous(labels = formatter(nsmall = 1))
```

[image]

The issue is, sometimes this approach is not practical. Take the leftmost plot from your figure, for example. Using the same formatting, all y-axis scale labels would be rounded up to `-0.3`, which is not preferable.

The other solution is to modify the breaks for each plot into a set of rounded values. But again, taking the leftmost plot of your figure as an example, it'll end up with just one label point, `-0.3`

Yet another solution is to format the labels into scientific form. For simplicity, you can modify the `formatter` function as follow:

```
formatter <- function(...){
  function(x) format(x, ..., scientific = T, digit = 2)
}
```

[image]

Now you can have a uniform format for all of plots' y-axis. My suggestion, though, is to set the label with 2 decimal places after rounding.

---

2. Wrap facet titles

This can be done using `labeller` argument in `facet_wrap`.

```
# Modify cyl into factors
mtcars2$cyl <- c("Four Cylinder", "Six Cylinder", "Eight Cylinder")[match(mtcars2$cyl, c(4,6,8))]

# Redraw the graph
sp <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, scales = "free_y", labeller = labeller(cyl = label_wrap_gen(width = 10)))
sp <- sp + scale_y_continuous(labels = formatter(nsmall = 2))
```

[image]

It must be noted that the wrap function detects space to separate labels into lines. So, in your case, you might need to modify your variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response! I decided to leave the y axis scaling as is, since some plots require more decimal places than others. As for the wrapping titles, I used `data$gene <- gsub('_',' ', data$gene)` to replace all the _ with spaces. Then, by adding `labeller = labeller(gene = label_wrap_gen(width = 30)` to my `facet_wrap` statement, I was able to successfully wrap gene name. Thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelStudivan Great! Glad it helps

Answer (score 1):

This only solved the first part of the question. You can create a function to format your axis and use `scale_y_continous` to adjust it.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(11), y1=seq(2, 3, 0.1) + 10, y2=rnorm(11))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- melt(df, 'x')

# Before
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scale="free")
```

[image]

```
# label function
f <- function(x){
  format(round(x, 1), nsmall=1)
}

# After
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scale="free") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=f)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`scale_*_continuous(..., labels = function(x) sprintf("%0.0f", x))` worked in my case.